# Losing Session variable on updating values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I am using asp .net 4 using mvc framework.
When I update a value, my session gets lost.
I cannot seem to figure out why. I am new to ASP.

Lets say I have `Session["sValue"] (= "test")`.
After executing the `Index()`, that variable is lost

> **Note:** It only happens if `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CallPrice)` is True, so CallPrice has a value.

**The Controller:**

```
// GET: Settings
[Route("Settings")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SettingsModel pageSettings = new SettingsModel();
    string CallPrice = Request.QueryString[pageSettings.Query_CallPrice];
    ViewBag.Result = "";

    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CallPrice))
        {
            pageSettings.Price = Convert.ToInt32(CallPrice);
            SettingsManager.call_price = CallPrice;
            ViewBag.Result = "Update Succesful.";
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CallPrice))
            pageSettings.Price = Convert.ToInt32(SettingsManager.call_price);

        ViewBag.Result = "Error Occured (Incorrect format provided)";
    }

    return View(pageSettings);
}
```

**The Page:**

```
@model Actacom3CX.Models.SettingsModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "3CX Settings";
}
<head>
    @{
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[Actacom3CX.Classes.Statics.SESSION_USERNAME] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/UserLogon", false);
        }else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[Actacom3CX.Classes.Statics.SESSION_USERNAME] = HttpContext.Current.Session[Actacom3CX.Classes.Statics.SESSION_USERNAME];
        }
    }
</head>
<div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top: 0em; padding-bottom:0.4em;padding-top:0.5em;">
    <div align="center">
        <h2 style="margin:0em;padding:0em;">
            @ViewBag.Title
        </h2>

        <h3 align="center">
            @{
                Output.Write(ViewBag.Result);
            }
        </h3>

    </div>
</div>



<div class="row">
    <form id="settingsForm" method="get" action="~/Settings">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="text" name=@{Output.Write(Model.Query_CallPrice);} value=@{Output.Write(Model.Price);} /><b style="padding-left: 1em;">Cent per minuut</b>
        <br /><br />
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Update &raquo;" />
    </form>
</div>
```

> **UPDATE**

The Session getting lost is happening in the following piece of code, in the SettingsManager:

```
public static void SetSetting(string key, string value)
{
    Configuration configuration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
    configuration.Save();
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}
```

Comment: I think your session value never changes because you are assigning it from itself! (In your view after `else`)

Comment: Updated code, found Where it happens but not why

Comment: What is the detail of the error?

Comment: @NickProzee - It seems you are updating the web.config file. When that is updated, the webapp restarts, which causes all Sessions to get lost (even from other users!).

Comment: Guess that explains... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Hans Kesting:

It seems you are updating the web.config file. When that is updated, the webapp restarts, which causes all Sessions to get lost (even from other users!).